# Set of data needs to be rearranged and exported as CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a set of data and it needs to be rearranged with header. PowerShell is a quick way, I think, to do this.

The data as an example:

```
AAA,
123,53,145,
text1 text12,text2,23.00,
21,6,0.21,0.00,2,
1,321,4
BBB,1,421,5,
text3 text34,
text4,41,22.5,1,
23,674,75,8,5....
```

As you can see the ',' seperates the values and the dot is just part of the value. The AAA and BBB represent the names and the values for AAA are before BBB. I expect the values to be like this within CSV file with each value in a new cell:

```
Name: AAA
abc:  123
def: 53
ghi: 145
jkl: text1 text12
mno: text2
pqr: 23.00
stu: 21
vwx: 6
yz: 0
```

Or the header would be like: Name abc def etc. and the values in the next cell under the header.

In total there are 16 values separated by a comma for one name (ex. AAA). There are maybe hundreds of names with random values.

I didn't get the result with `Sort-Object`, because it would scan the data and put the values in random order.

Comment: what pattern is there to the start/end of a group of data? your sample shows 15 items in the 1st group, and only 14 in the 2nd [apparently truncated] group. ///// so ... how do you know where a group starts and ends?

Comment: The start is with the name (AAA)  and the end is before the new name begins (BBB) there are exactly 18 values (property) seperated by ',' for each name  and each property has its own name(abc). So the group starts with the name and ends after 18th value and then the new group starts. indeed I couldn't write all of it down, that is why you saw the difference.

Comment: there are EXACTLY 15 items before the `BBB` - including the `AAA` - in your sample. how do you account for that? your sample does not meet your specification ... and your specification has changed from 16 properties to 18 properties. ///// so ... what is the actual specification? [*frown*]

Comment: Why is it so important that in the first example there are 15 items before the name and what I explained after was there are 18 items. To discuss the amount of items while I explained afterwards the exact amount is not really a good discussion point. So to be clear the example in the first post was an estimate and there are exactly 18 items after each name fyi.

Comment: Are there **really** line breaks in each group, or is there each group in one separate line for a particular name?

Comment: the reason specifications are important is to make sure one is doing what is intended. you have shown THREE different sets of specifications. how can anyone lay out a code design when the spec changes apparently at random? ///// so ... the 3rd spec - name + 18 properties - is the real one?

Comment: There are really line breaks in each group and the group, including the name, are not on seperate line they are just underneath eachother.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes, the 3rd one (name + 18 properties) is the real one

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do the job. it presumes that there are 18 properties and that each object ends with a line that does NOT end with a comma.

the resulting collection can be gracefully sent to a CSV via `Export-CSV`. [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a text file as one multi-line string
#    in real life, use Get-Content -Raw
# similar names & properties are NOT part of the data
#    they are there for visually crosschecking the output
$InStuff = @'
Object_A,
A1,A2,A3,
A4 some other stuff,A5,
A6,A7 more extras,A8,A9,A10.00,
A11,A12,A13 thirteen,A14,
A15,A16.666,A17,A18
Object_B,B1.1,B2.2,B3.3,
B4 some other stuff,B5,B6,B7 more extras,B8,B9,B10.00,
B11,B12,B13 thirteen,B14,
B15,B16.666,B17,B18
'@

$ColumnHeaders = ('Name' +
    ' Col_01 Col_02 Col_03 Col_04 Col_05 Col_06 Col_07 Col_08 Col_09 Col_10' +
    ' Col_11 Col_12 Col_13 Col_14 Col_15 Col_16 Col_17 Col_18') -split ' '

$CSV = $InStuff -split "(?<!,)$([environment]::NewLine)" | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace ",$([environment]::NewLine)", ','
        }

$Results = $CSV |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $ColumnHeaders

$Results
```

output ...

```
Name   : Object_A
Col_01 : A1
Col_02 : A2
Col_03 : A3
Col_04 : A4 some other stuff
Col_05 : A5
Col_06 : A6
Col_07 : A7 more extras
Col_08 : A8
Col_09 : A9
Col_10 : A10.00
Col_11 : A11
Col_12 : A12
Col_13 : A13 thirteen
Col_14 : A14
Col_15 : A15
Col_16 : A16.666
Col_17 : A17
Col_18 : A18

Name   : Object_B
Col_01 : B1.1
Col_02 : B2.2
Col_03 : B3.3
Col_04 : B4 some other stuff
Col_05 : B5
Col_06 : B6
Col_07 : B7 more extras
Col_08 : B8
Col_09 : B9
Col_10 : B10.00
Col_11 : B11
Col_12 : B12
Col_13 : B13 thirteen
Col_14 : B14
Col_15 : B15
Col_16 : B16.666
Col_17 : B17
Col_18 : B18
```